# Static file or memory based web server cache for Coldfusion and IIS

Tags: nginx, iis, coldfusion, isapi

We are looking for a cache layer between IIS/ISAPI and Coldfusion, so that if an entire page is cached on the server, then additional requests to that resource do not require allocating a Coldfusion thread. I think this is almost identical to nginx + memcached but unfortunately we do not have the luxury of using those =(.

Here is an example of the communication pathways that I envision:

GET request for /hotels/?listingid=5 -> cache -> exists and fresh -> serve

GET request for /hotels/?listingid=10 -> cache -> exists but stale -> Coldfusion -> cache -> serve

GET request to cache from coldfusion to clear out /hotels/?listingid=10.

GET request for /hotels/?listingid=10&nocache -> Coldfusion

I don't mind rolling my own even if I had to code some C++, but I don't even know where to start.

Comment: I've great success with CacheBox. You can also do some work with caching directly in ColdFusion via the <cfcache /> tag. There are lots of improvements in CF9 and CF10. If you're on those later versions, you also have access to Ehcache.

Comment: The `cfcache`, `cachePut()` and `cacheGet()` functions work great. But even if we cache an entire page with cfcache it still requires a coldfusion thread to serve that page. We want to be able to serve cached content without the thread.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you have a query string in your URL, that means the content is dynamically generated. Some program, in this case ColdFusion evaluates the query string to figure out what to do with it. I would stress test the `<cfcache>` based solution to see if you are experiencing latency. When I get a high traffic website I focus on the following areas:

- Is the db keeping up with the request load
- Are the db resources being used efficiently
- Load balancing / failover / standby servers
- Can I get more memory for the web servers
- How are the CF server logs doing

Every situation is different, but the speed of page request thread generation has just never come up